# why aren't menus pre-inflated for you?

Tags: android, menu, inflate

Why aren't menus inflated automatically for you in Android, the way an Activity's layout is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are, just override like this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.YOUR_MENU_LAYOUT, menu);
        return true;    
    }
```

EDIT, heres a sample xml, they go in `/res/menu`

```
<menu>
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_sample"
          android:title="Sample text"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_sample"
     />

</menu>
```

Comment: Here is what I am confused about:  The overridden code that you suggest I provide, contains statements that explicitly inflate the XML file.

However, my Activity layouts need no such action.

So my question is not "how" do I inflate a menu, but "WHY" is this needed?  Why aren't menus inflated automatically, like Activity layouts are?

Thanks

Comment: But the layouts are inflated in the same fashion, just with one API call `setContentView(layout)`. 

They 'why' part of your question could be as simple as "To make it easier to add sub menus"

Take this example. I have an abstract class that extends Activity. It inflates a set of common actions available for the menu options. In the sub classes I use for activities I dynamically add specific options using `addSubMenu(int groupId, int itemId, int order, int titleRes)` This way I don't need to copy and paste xml all over the place.

Answer (score 3):

You *do* explicitly inflate your activity layout with `setContentView(R.layout.whatever)`. It doesn't have inflate in the name, but that (among a few other things) is what it does.